# I am Not Able to change the status of the button through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my following code in front End:

```
                             <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading text-center text-uppercase">Birth Certificates For Overall (Pending, Completed)</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                  <table id="viewer" class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Sr No</th>
                                        <th>Reg Number</th>
                                        <th>From Hospital</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                      </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php $Viewer->showAllData(); ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Sr No</th>
                                        <th>Reg Number</th>
                                        <th>From Hospital</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                  </table>
                                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                              </div><!-- /.box -->
                            </div>
```

This is my classes code in it of which i have called the object:

```
    public function showAllData()
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM certificate_details ORDER BY created DESC";
                    $connection = $this->establish_connection();
                    $details = $connection->query($query);
                    $connection->close();

                    if($details->num_rows > 0)
                        {
                            $counter = 1;
                            while($detail = $details->fetch_assoc())
                                {
                                    $status = $detail['status'];

                                    if($status == 0)
                                        {
                                            $bg = "bg-danger";
                                            $issuestatus = "btn btn-success";
                                            $message = "Confirm Issue!";
                                        }
                                    elseif($status == 1)
                                        {
                                            $bg = "bg-success";
                                            $issuestatus = "btn btn-success disabled";
                                            $message = "Certificate Issued";
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            $bg = "bg-warning";
                                            $issuestatus = "btn btn-warning";
                                        }

                                    echo "
                                            <tr class='odd gradeX ".$bg."'>
                                                <td>".$counter."</td>
                                                <td>".$detail['registration_number']."</td>
                                                <td>".$this->getHospitalInfo($detail['user_id'])."</td>
                                                <td style='margin: 0;'><div class='btn btn-primary' href='#' value='".$detail['id']."' id='view-details'>View Details</div><div style='margin-left: 10px;' class='".$issuestatus."' href='#' value='".$detail['id']."' id='confirm-issue'>".$message."</div></td>
                                            </tr>    
                                         ";
                                    $counter = $counter + 1;
                                }
                        }
                }
```

I have give a specific class to the button i.e class="confirm-issue" and in the value section it hold the unique value

This is the following JQuery Code which i am triggering whenever i am calling the     ("#confirm-issue").click(function(){})

```
      $("body").on("click", ".confirm-issue",function() 
        {
            var certificateId = $(this).attr('value');

            if (confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Confirm The Issue of Certificate? If Once Confirmed Can\'t be Undone.\n\t\t\t\t\tPlease Confirm That You Have Issued The Certificate.'))
                {
                    $.ajax({
                                url: 'get_data.php?id=setCertificateDetailsIssued',
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'html',
                                data: {certificate_id : certificateId},
                            })
                    .done(function(resp)
                        {
                            console.log(resp);
                            if(resp == 1)
                                {
                                    var data = "Certificate Issued Succesfully!";
                                    $(this).attr('value').val("Certificate Isssued").attr('disabled', 'true');
                                    $('#message').html("");
                                    $('#message').html(data);
                                    $('#messageModal h3.modal-title').html('');
                                    $('#messageModal h3.modal-title').html('Certificate Issued Successfully!');
                                    $('#messageModal').modal('show');
                                }

                            else if(resp == 0)
                                {
                                    var data = "There Was a Technical Error While Setting The Certificate Status To Issued. Please Try After Some Time Or Try Reloading The Page Once Again!";
                                    $('#message').html("");
                                    $('#message').html(data);
                                    $('#messageModal h3.modal-title').html('');
                                    $('#messageModal h3.modal-title').html('Technical Issue!');
                                    $('#viewer tr.gradeX').removeClass('bg-danger');
                                    $('#messageModal').modal('show');
                                }
                        })
                    .fail(function()
                        {
                            console.log("error");
                        });
                }
            else
                {
                    var data = "Please Confirm That You Have Issued The Certificate & Then Click Confirm Issue Again!";
                    $('#message').html("");
                    $('#message').html(data);
                    $('#messageModal h3.modal-title').html('');
                    $('#messageModal h3.modal-title').html('Confirmation Prompt');
                    $('#messageModal').modal('show');
                }
        });
```

The problem arises when I click on issue certificate button. The value is going to the database, is being altered, and the resp code is 1, but when the control is going to the function where if condition is met as shown in the provided js code, it isn't executing the particular JQuery code to disable the button.

[image]

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: means @MVCE i didn't get u

Comment: Click on the link I posted, and you will get it.

Comment: Trim down your code to show only the parts that are in error. You don't need the php if you think the response is correct. This question should only show the html for the button and the javascript that is supposed to manipulate it, the rest is just extraneous information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax there...

```
$(this).attr('value').val("Certificate Isssued").attr('disabled', 'true');
```

instead make it...

```
$(this).val("Certificate Isssued");
$(this).attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Comment: You're welcome, please validate my Answer. Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies with your misconception that `this` still refers to the button. It doesn't. You need to use another var to reference the button.

```
var that = this;
if (confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Confirm The Issue of Certificate? .....'))
{
    $.ajax({
         url: 'get_data.php?id=setCertificateDetailsIssued',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'html',
         data: {certificate_id : certificateId}
     })
      .done(function(resp)
       {
           console.log(resp);
           if(resp == 1)
           {
               var data = "Certificate Issued Succesfully!";
                $(that).attr('value', "Certificate isssued").attr('disabled', 'true');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't look correct:

```
$(this).attr('value').val("Certificate Isssued").attr('disabled', 'true');
```

You are trying to get a value by attribute and then calling val function on that. Try changing it to:

```
$(this).val("Certificate Isssued").attr('disabled', 'true');
```